# sign an access token request for the tumblr api winrt

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth, windows-runtime, tumblr

I make it through the tumblr request token and the authorization and getting the oauth token and the secret, but the final step of acquiring access tokens is where is keep getting the error `oauth_signature does not match expected value`.

```
// the code which is used for getting the access tokens

    private async Task<bool> GetAccessTokensAsync()
        {
            string accesTokenUrl = "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token";
            string accesTokenUrl2 = "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token";
            string nonce = GetNonce();
            string timeStamp = GetTimeStamp();
            string BaseParameters = "oauth_consumer_key=" + aouthKey;
            BaseParameters += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + nonce;
            BaseParameters += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1";
            BaseParameters += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + timeStamp;
            BaseParameters += "&" + "oauth_token=" +"oauth token got after authorization";

            BaseParameters += "&" + "oauth_version=1.0";
            String protocol = "GET&";
            protocol += Uri.EscapeDataString(accesTokenUrl) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(BaseParameters);
            string signature = GetSignature(protocol, aouthSecret);

HttpStringContent httpContent = new HttpStringContent("oauth_verifier=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth verifier got after authorization"), Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            string authparams = "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + aouthKey + "\", oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce + "\", oauth_signature_method=\"" + "HMAC-SHA1" + "\", oauth_signature=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(signature) + "\", oauth_timestamp=\"" + timeStamp + "\", oauth_token=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth token got after authorization") + "\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("OAuth", authparams);
            HttpResponseMessage respMe = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(accesTokenUrl),httpContent);
            string response = await respMe.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("response is " + response);

}

// the consumer key, consumer secret and the callback url.


     string aouthKey = "######";
       string aouthSecret = "####";
       string callbackURL = "https://localhost";

//function for getting the nonce


     string GetNonce()
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int nonce = rand.Next(1000000000);

                return nonce.ToString();
            }

//function for generating the timestamp


     string GetTimeStamp()
            {
                TimeSpan SinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                return Math.Round(SinceEpoch.TotalSeconds).ToString();
            }



// function for generating the signature from microsofts examples.


     string GetSignature(string sigBaseString, string consumerSecretKey)
            {
                IBuffer KeyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(consumerSecretKey + "&", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
                MacAlgorithmProvider HmacSha1Provider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
                CryptographicKey MacKey = HmacSha1Provider.CreateKey(KeyMaterial);
                IBuffer DataToBeSigned = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(sigBaseString,BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
                IBuffer SignatureBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Sign(MacKey, DataToBeSigned);
                string Signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(SignatureBuffer);

                return Signature;
            }
```

Now I have tried using POST,GET SORTING using twitter protocols.
https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures#note-sorting

I have even tried using the token secret got during the first request and the consumer keys for signing the request.

I have matched the token got during the initial request and the token got after authorization and they both were the same as they should be. One thing though , is #*=* part of the aouth verifier got after authorization. I have used with it and without it and it made no difference.

Thanks